# What are the factors affecting video file size

Tags: video, file-upload, image-uploading, filesize

I want to send various video files from different CCTVs over the internet.  To minimiz bandwidth usage and time of upload, I'd like to understand the various factors that affect the file size, so I can arrive at the right mix.  All related info is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY factors are bitrate and duration. Multiply them together and you get the size. Now bitrate will affect video quality, so you must find the balance for your application.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary!  Don't number of frames per second count?  As that is not a critical requirement for my purpose, I was planning to reduce that to reduce file size. Could you give me some advise on that?

Comment: I did put the word 'only' in all caps :) If you have a fixed bitrate, and a high frame rate, its fewer bits per frame.

Comment: Would I be right in saying bitrate is a derivative function of FPS and Resolution?

Comment: No. You can have 1080p 30 fps at 4mpbs and you can have 1080p 30fps ate 20mpbs. Obviously, 20mbps will look better, but they both have the same resolution and framerare

Comment: Wow!, So, I need even more clarity... what are the other factors that affect the Bit Rate?

Comment: @SrikrishnaVadrevu search for "constant rate factor"

Comment: Thanks again... will do